# Android Studio: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am currently having this error. I am using API 21 and I know some folks here suggested to upgrade it to API 22 base on previous questions but the tutorial(Slidenerd of Youtube) I am following is using API 21 and did not encountered any errors like this. Weird thing also because my RecyclerView in emulator is just working fine as expected in his tutorial and I don't why this error keeps popping up. Thanks !

[image: Image of the Error:]

[image: Image of emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error. Because the constructor is getting called while viewing the layout. Normally there are some operations which are going to be executed. To avoid this there is `View.isInEditMode()`.

Normally you would use it like this

```
public Constructor(){
  if(View.isInEditMode())
    return;
}
```

Comment: HI there! where should I insert this ?

Comment: @M.Panhwar It is a issue on the developer site. Not yours.

Comment: @M.Panhwar Yes you do it for now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are talking about the message the preview window of your layout is giving you?

You are probably using a version of recycler view that is newer than your compile version.

In you build.gradle file where you have added recyclerview to your dependencies you can try downgrading the version you are using

Change `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'`
to `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'` (or change to a 21.x.x version that suits your needs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am currently using: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+' and this still pops up.